# Why is "sqlservr" causing regular CPU spikes?

Tags: windows, task-manager

[image: CPU peaks]

I have checked the services, CPU and I have noticed that indeed it is `sqlservr.exe` that grabs the attention of my CPU (the next screenshot shows a short peak in `sqlservr`'s CPU usage).

It happens regularly as in the first image. But – it is a quite new installation of the system, I haven't  even been working on this computer with SQL yet, I haven't install anything related to SQL either. What is `sqlsrvr` is doing then?

[image]

Comment: On my computer it is the process sqlservr.exe which makes exactly 5 peaks every 60 seconds. The peaks in one series are separated by approx. 1 second.

Answer (score 1):

You can sort your services by processor usage by clicking services, and then clicking the column header that says CPU... This may help you hunt down the process using processor resources.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) which can tell you even after those spikes happened which process was responsible for them.

However, it could well be that it'd just be *svchost* at which point you might need to investigate which service is at fault.

Comment: it looks like it is sqlservr.exe

Comment: Then stop the service if you don't need SQL Server.